# Entire functions with prescribed values and growth

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $a_n \to \infty$ and the $A_n$ are arbitrary complex numbers. From Ahlfors' Complex Analysis exercise 1 in section 5.2.3, we know that there exists an entire function $f$ which satisfies $f(a_n)=A_n$. I know that the proof is based on the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem and the Mittag-Leffler Theorem. In fact, the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(z)\frac{e^{\gamma_n(z-a_n)}}{z-a_n} \cdot \frac{A_n}{g'(a_n)},
\end{equation} where $g$ is an entire function with simple zeros at the $a_n$ and $\gamma$ are some choices of complex numbers so that the series converges. I wonder if we can choose or modify the function $g(z)$ or the numbers $\gamma_n$ so that $f$ is of a given (finite) order. Any ideas?

Comment: For example if $A_n=0$ for all $n$ and $a_n$ is in size like $\log n$ the function cannot have finite order as the number of zeroes of a function of order $a$ cannot be more than roughly (could have a logarithmic factor $\log R$) $R^a$ in a ball of radius $R$ from jensen

Comment: @Conrad, I see the point. What if $A_n=0$ for only finitely many $n$?

Comment: it doesn't matter as long as $a_n$ are close to each other - of course there will be entire functions of finite order for various values of $A_n$ even if you take $a_n=\log n$ but you will need strong conditions on $A_n$ (they will need to be spaced quite apart); if $a_n$ are spaced like the integers there are interpolation formulas that give functions of exponential type; you should look up this topic in texts on entire functions (Levin, Boas etc) where the topic is covered in detail at least for $a_n=n$ and similar